# How to use sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif properly?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My goal is to do Feature Selection. However, I am confused because:

1. There is parameter `discrete_features`.

   The current solution is to fill `discrete_features` like this:

   1. nominal features that was one hot encoded is set to True
   2. numerical features that was scaled is set to False
   3. ordinal features that was ordinal encoded is set to True

```
def isolate():
    composer.fit(X=X_train)
    X_train_final = composer.transform(X=X_train)
    y_train_final = y_train.map({'No': 0, 'Yes': 1})
    mi = mutual_info_classif(
        X=X_train_final, 
        y=y_train_final,
        discrete_features=[feature.startswith("nom") for feature in composer.get_feature_names_out()]
    )
    df_c = pd.DataFrame()
    df_c['mi'] = mi
    df_c['feature'] = composer.get_feature_names_out()
    display(df_c.sort_values(by='mi', ascending=False).style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm'))

isolate()
```

I am not sure whether `mutual_info_classif` can know that `nom__OnlineSecurity_No Internet Service`, `nom__OnlineSecurity_Yes`, `nom__OnlineSecurity_No` is one feature.

[image]